Compact-by-discrete Hausdorff topological ring that isn't totally disconnected
I'm trying to find an example of a topological Hausdorff ring $R$ such that $R$ contains a compact open subgroup while not being totally disconnected.
In particular, it cannot contain any compact subring (it's possible to prove that if it did, it would have to be totally disconnected).
Edit: It's also possible to show that if $H$ is such compact open subgroup, then $S = \{r \in R: rH \subset H\}$ is an open subring of $R$, and $H \cap S$ is a compact open left ideal of $S$. Since $S$ is open  subring of $R$, $R$ is totally disconnected if and only if $S$ is. This implies that we can suppose without loss of generality that $R$ contains a compact open left ideal.
Edit 2: All rings here are unital (and subrings are required to contain the same identity element), this is quite important to make certain arguments work!

Let $A$ be any topological abelian group that is compact Hausdorff and not totally disconnected. Turn $A$ into a topological non-unital ring by defining all multiplications to be zero: $a\cdot b=0$ for all $a,b \in A$.
Now consider the unitalization $\Bbb Z\oplus A$. The underlying abelian group of this is the usual direct sum. Multiplication is defined by $(n_1,a_1)(n_2,a_2)=(n_1n_2,n_1a_2+n_2a_1+a_1a_2)=(n_1n_2,n_1a_2+n_2a_1)$. With the product topology (with respect to the discrete topology on $\Bbb Z$), the unitalization becomes a topological unital ring which contains $A$ as an open compact ideal.
